# How to make pandas.style.to_latex() output header fields enclosed in {}?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, latex

I'm producing several LateX tables through python/pandas.
Up until recently, the tables' headers were enclosed in `{}`, without any explicit instruction for that, ie:

```
\begin{tabular}{llrrr}
{} & {date} & {x} & {y} & {z} \\
{} & {(yyyy-mm-dd)} & {(s)} & {(m)} & {(kg)} \\
0 & 2014-03-12 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 2014-03-13 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\end{tabular}
```

But recently, the output from pandas.style.to_latex() started being the following (without the `{}`):

```
\begin{tabular}{llrrr}
 & date & x & y & z \\
 & (yyyy-mm-dd) & (s) & (m) & (kg) \\
0 & 2014-03-12 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 2014-03-13 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
\end{tabular}
```

As I'm post-processing these LateX tables in python, I need the headers to be enclosed in `{}`

Does anyone know what I must do for that?

The original pandas dataframe can be generated through:

```
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    zip(['date', 'x', 'y', 'z'],
        ['(yyyy-mm-dd)', '(s)', '(m)', '(kg)']))
data = [['2014-03-12', 1, 2, 3],
        ['2014-03-13', 4, 5, 6]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
```

Comment: Would you care to clarify why there's a negative vote?

Comment: A negative vote with no explanation serves no constructive purpose...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two ways,

```
df.style.to_latex(siunitx=True)
```

(since siunitx package requires this formatting)

or

```
df.style.format_index("{{{0}}}", axis=1).to_latex()
```

(explicitly using the format function to control the output)

Comment: AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'format_index'

Comment: @lefterav: Update your pandas >= 1.4.0  - https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format_index.html